# Remapping mouse button

Tags: remapping

I want to remap my middle mouse button to simulate alt-tab (switch between running applications) on ubuntu 12.04.   How would I do that?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an end-of-life release.

Comment: I believe the question had been sufficiently reworded, perhaps the question is not off-topic any more and should be reopened.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 10.04 LTS is outdated (and therefore unsupported) for desktops. I would therefore advise you to first upgrade to 12.04 LTS, and then ask another question on AU.

Comment: Fine, how about for 12.04 LTS?

Comment: Please edit the question in case, and I will ask to have it reopened.

Comment: Ok, I updated the question